# App live on Facebook for public

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have toggled the switch on App Review to "yes" so that it could be live and available to public. However, it does seems to be the case. As public users are not able to search for the page and start conversation on the messenger. Only accounts that are under the developer role are able to start the conversation.

If possible, please advise on the issue.

[image: Toggled Switch to live]

Answer (score 0):

To make your page visible to user you have to change the status of your facebook page to public too from page settings.

Page Settings->General-> Page Visibility

And for messenger bot you have to submit your app for review to the facebook. After approval your user can interact with your bot.

[App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/app-review)

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted the Send API (Pages Messaging) for approval yet? This is found in Product- settings of the Developer App dashboard.

After you have done this, a tester will check some questions and answers you provide to ensure the bot works correctly. It will then be live.